# Returning String from actionPerformed and actionListener Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I've created a simple program where you choose a file and, hopefully, have the string of the file path returned, I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
public static String createWindow() {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox Test");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton inbutton = new JButton("Select Input File");

    inbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       String imagePath;

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
          int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
          if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
             File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
             imagePath = selectedFile.getPath();
          }
       }
    });

    frame.add(inbutton);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    return imagePath;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Explain more please, what you expected, what do you actually get?

Comment: the error is that imagePath cannot be resolved to a variable, I want it to contain the file path

Comment: This should be part of the original question.

Comment: The return statement is executed right after the frame is visible.  You don't have a chance to click on a button.  You need to call a GUI model class method in your actioPerformed module after you've had a chance to set the imagePath field.  Read all of the Oracle Java Swing tutorials.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to return a value immediately when the method is called, but the result won't be available until some event occurs. Your logic is off. What you should do is display the button in a modal dialog not a JFrame. The modality of the dialog will effectively pause program flow from the point where the dialog is displayed until the dialog is no longer visible.

Comment: How do I do that? I am pretty new to java, any suggested tutorials?

Comment: @user1750156 Make it a field of the class. And next time tell us about all errors in your question! Check out the Java Swing tutorials.

Comment: @user1750156 Check out [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)